# How to play live camera view in ReactJS using RTSP

Tags: reactjs, rtsp

How to play live camera view in ReactJS using RTSP. I have RTSP URL to play IP camera's video live how can we play

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import RTSPPlayer from "react-rtsp-player";

const CameraView =()=>{
    return (
      <RTSPPlayer
        url="rtsp://<camera-ip-address>:<port>/<stream>"
        controls={true}
      />
      );
}

export default CameraView;
```

Comment: npm install react-rtsp-player
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-rtsp-player - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'react-rtsp-player@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: I can not install react-rtsp-player on my react project

Comment: try react-player, react-video, or react-native-vlc-player these all supports RSTP